# How to show 2do Lists in Alfred?

Tags: alfred

I used Alfred and 2Do a lot. And what I want is to list all the 2do tasks in Alfred, I've searched a way to solve it.

Is there a way to fetch all the 2Do tasks and shown it in Alfred?

Answer (score 0):

No. 2Do does not provide AppleScript support nor a proper API.